# Proving a certain holomorphic function is polinomic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula, maximum-principle

Suppose we have an holomorphic function $f$ on the open unit disk $D(0,1)$ s.t.:

$$\forall r\in (0,1) \exists n\in \mathbb{N}| \max_{C(0,r)}|f|=r^n$$

prove that $f$ is polinomic. Honestly I don't know where to start, every approach I take leads me to triviality or useless formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $f$ has a zero of $n$-th order at $z=0$. Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ and observe that $g$ attains maximum modulus in the interior.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I've misread the problem. We cannot draw directly from the statement the fact that there is an independent $n$ such that $\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|=r^n$ holds. What we have is $n(r)\geq 1$ such that $$ \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|=r^{n(r)}.$$To see there is independent $n$, note that
$$
\phi(r) = \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|
$$ is continuous in $r\in(0,1)$ by the continuity of $f$. Thus, a positive integer-valued function
$$
n(r) = \frac{\phi(r)}{\log r}
$$ is also continuous, establishing $n(r) \equiv n$. If you feel this argument tricky, you can solve the problem inductively, by noting that if there are $r_1<r_2$ such that $n(r_1)=n(r_2)=m$ attains minimum of $n(\cdot)$, then we can argue by maximum modulus principle that $\frac{f(z)}{z^m}$ is a constant.

Comment: I can't see why it has a zero at the origin

Comment: Just take $r\to 0$ and use continuity. Divide $f$ by $z$ and do the same thing $n$ times.

Comment: Why does $g$ attains its maximum modulus in the interior?

Comment: It is because $\max_{|z|=r} |g(z)|=1$ for $0<r<1$. I'll explain it in more detail. So there is $w$ with $|w|=\frac{1}{3}$ such that $|g(w)|=1=\max_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}}|g(z)|$. Now, apply Maximum modulus principle.

Comment: @Song The hypothesis says for each $r$ there exist $n$ such that $\cdots$; so $n$ varies with $r$. Aren't you assuming that $n$ is independent of $r$?.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I realized I misread the statement. I've corrected my argument. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @Song I have given an upvote. Your answer is neat.